# What is difference between intel-compute-runtime, intel-opencl-runtime, and intel-opencl-sdk?

Tags: opencl, intel

It looks like that Intel provides many OpenCL implementations.[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GPGPU) describes OpenCL implementations. It says that beignet and intel-opencl are deprecated. Then, what is difference between intel-compute-runtime, intel-opencl-runtime, and intel-opencl-sdk?

I want to use OpenCL on my x86 computer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following **OpenCL runtimes** expose your Intel integrated **GPU** as an OpenCL device to applications in your PC:

- [Intel compute runtime](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime) (aka Neo) is the new open-source OpenCL implementation for Intel GPUs. It supports integrated GPUs from Broadwell and onward.
- [Beignet](https://01.org/beignet) is the old open-source OpenCL implementation for Intel integrated GPUs. It supports integrated GPUs since Ivy Bridge. You should use this if you have an older Intel processor.
- [Intel OpenCL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/legacy-opencl-drivers#latest_linux_driver) was a proprietary alternative to Beignet for older processors since Ivy Bridge. In my experience Beignet is preferable if you have an older processor.

The [Intel OpenCL runtime](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#cpu-section) exposes your **CPU** as an OpenCL device to applications in your PC.

An **OpenCL ICD loader** is vendor-independent and allows you to select which OpenCL device to use at runtime. There are several available, but I suggest [ocl-icd](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=ocl-icd), since it's open source and typically up-to-date.

For developing your own OpenCL programs you also need the **OpenCL headers**, which you can [download from here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers) or install from the [Arch repositories](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=opencl-headers).

The so called **SDKs** are simply vendor bundles that generally contain: a) an **OpenCL runtime** to expose the vendor hardware as an OpenCL device; b) an **OpenCL ICD loader**, so that various processors can be exposed as OpenCL devices; c) the **OpenCL headers**; d) code samples on how to best use OpenCL on the vendor hardware; and, e) possibly other vendor related stuff.

Some examples of SDKs include:

- AMD APP SDK (discontinued).
- [Intel® SDK for OpenCL™ Applications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/opencl-sdk).

You don't actually need an SDK to develop OpenCL applications, as long as you have an **OpenCL runtime**, an **OpenCL ICD loader** and the **OpenCL headers**. If developed in C/C++, your applications should include the headers and link against an ICD loader (`libOpenCL.so`).

Comment: What about the `opencl-mesa` package? I'm on an i5 3320M (Ivy Bridge, HD Graphics 4000) and did some stuff with mesa drivers, should I use `beignet` or this one?

Comment: @Margotka000 The opencl-mesa package may refer to mesa's old Clover OpenCL implementation, which is really limited, or the new Rusticl implementation, which is in better shape (probably it refers to the former, since Rusticl is in early days). Nowadays Intel is pushing their newer [NEO OpenCL](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime) implementation, but for older chips (e.g. Ivy Bridge), Beignet is probably still the way to go.